# Why is my array not passing to the fuction I created properly? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, parameter-passing

I need to write a function that checks if an array passed through it in order from smallest value to largest. The issue that I'm having is that the function is returning true for all arrays. I put a 'cout' statement within the function an noticed that the numbers did not match the array. For example, when 4 is pressed, since the array would be [30..1], it should return the array and that it is not ordered. Yet the actual return is:

```
18224
array is sorted
1
```

which is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

```
int isOrdered(int arr[], int n) {
if (n <= 1)   // array with 1 or no elements
    return 1; // is always sorted

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    cout << arr[i] << '  ';
    cout << endl;
    if (arr[i-1] >= arr[i]) {
        cout << "array is not sorted " << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
return 1;
}

int main() {
int input;

// Prompt for user
cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << " Press 1 to exit the program " << endl;
cout << " Press 2 to select the array that is sorted in increasing order " << endl;
cout << " Press 3 to select the array that is randomly sorted " << endl;
cout << " Press 4 to select the array that is sorted in decreasing order " << endl;
cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
cin >> input;

// catch if input not within bounds
while (input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && input != 4)
{
    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << " Press 1 to exit the program " << endl;
    cout << " Press 2 to select the array that is sorted in increasing order " << endl;
    cout << " Press 3 to select the array that is randomly sorted " << endl;
    cout << " Press 4 to select the array that is sorted in decreasing order " << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cin >> input;
}

while (input != 1)
{
    int n = 30;

    int* a = new int[n];
    int* b = new int[n];
    int* c = new int[n];

    int* a_c = new int[n];
    int* b_c = new int[n];
    int* c_c = new int[n];

    if (input == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = i + 1;
        }

        // duplicated array needed to be created per instructions 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a_c[i] = a[i];
        }

        cout << isOrdered(a_c, n) << endl;
        
    }

    else if (input == 3) {
        /* seed the PRNG (MT19937) using a variable value (in our case, s)*/
        std::mt19937 generator(1); // seed by variable input
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1, n); // random numbers need to be in range between 1, n

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            b[i] = distribution(generator);
            //cout << b[i] << ' '; // testing
        }

        // create duplicate 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            b_c[i] = b[i];
            cout << b_c[i] << ' ';
        }

        cout << isOrdered(b, n) << endl;
    }

    else {
        for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            c[i] = i + 1;
        }
        
        // create duplicate 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            c_c[i] = c[i];
        }

        cout << isOrdered(c_c, n) << endl;
    }

    // Prompt user again
    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << " Press 1 to exit the program " << endl;
    cout << " Press 2 to select the array that is sorted in increasing order " << endl;
    cout << " Press 3 to select the array that is randomly sorted " << endl;
    cout << " Press 4 to select the array that is sorted in decreasing order " << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cin >> input;

    // catch if input not within bounds
    while (input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && input != 4)
    {
        cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << " Press 1 to exit the program " << endl;
        cout << " Press 2 to select the array that is sorted in increasing order " << endl;
        cout << " Press 3 to select the array that is randomly sorted " << endl;
        cout << " Press 4 to select the array that is sorted in decreasing order " << endl;
        cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cin >> input;
    }
}

exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `isOrdered` contains a loop, but it always returns on the first iteration of that loop. It never proceeds past comparing `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`

Comment: **Read a [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) then [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)**. Use preferably [C++ standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). **Read also the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a potential for *Undefined Behavior* iterating from `i = 0; i < n` and accessing `arr[i+1]` -- which will be one past the end of the array when `i == n - 1`. "Potential" because you never get there -- you are returning on your first iteration.

Instead, why not simply do:

```
int isOrdered(int arr[], int n) {
    
    int i = 1;
    
    for (; i < n; i++)
        if (a[i-1] > a[i])
            break;
    
    return i == n ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `isOrdered` return a `bool` ?

Comment: I would think so, but the OP had `int` and `1` and `-1` as the return -- a valid, albeit uncommon way to go. (it would make the return simpler, just `return i == n;`)

Answer (score 2):

1. You do create a sorted array [1..30] (you just start from the end while filling it) - to create [30..1] you'd need `c[i] = n - i;` and you don't need to loop backwards then.
2. You are checking only the first elements and then you immediately return from the function, so [5,6,1,2] would also be "sorted" because you look only at 5 and 6. You should return as "sorted" only when you are done with the whole loop without running into the "unsorted" condition, so put your "sorted" conclusion *outside* of the loop.
3. You access one element beyond the end of the array due to `i < n` instead of `i < n - 1`, which is dangerous undefined behavior (and will mess up your result).

Also, side note: Stepping through your code using a debugger would be a tremendous help for you to understand what is going wrong, and you wouldn't need to ask here every time something is not working. You would have noticed that the array actually contains ascending instead of descending numbers, and you would also have noticed that the comparison function returns after one check only, instead of looping.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is `return`'ing on the 1st iteration regardless of the contents of the entire array. You need to `return false` as soon as you detect a mismatch, but do not `return true` until the loop has finished checking the entire array and did not detect a mismatch, eg:

```cpp
bool isOrdered(int arr[], int n) {
    if (n < 1) {
        cout << "array is empty" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    cout << arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << ' ' << arr[i];
        if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1]) {
            cout << "array is not sorted" << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    cout << "array is sorted" << endl;
    return true;
}
```